# Switch pattern matching for instanceof returns always null

Tags: java, intellij-idea, switch-statement, pattern-matching

I am trying to assign the result of the following `instanceof pattern matching switch` to the variable `languageCodeOfReturnValue`.

```
    String languageCodeOfReturnValue = switch (object){
                case PlantGuidePageWrapperDTO plantGuidePageWrapperDTO -> plantGuidePageWrapperDTO.getSeedDetailsDTO().getPageSummaryLanguageCode();
                case JournalEntryDetailsDTO journalEntryDetailsDTO -> journalEntryDetailsDTO.getLanguageCode();
                case JournalOverviewDTO journalOverviewDTO -> journalOverviewDTO.getPageSummaryLanguageCode();
                default -> null;
    };
```

But this code causes the following warning:

> Value 'switch (object){ case PlantGuidePageWrapperDTO
> plantGuidePageWrapperDTO -> plant...' is always 'null'

When i remove the `default` clause the warning disappears but then i'm left with a syntax error because then the `switch` doesn't cover all possible values. The warning disappears when i replace `null` with and empty string `''`. However i really want the default value to be `null`.

So my question is twofold: **First, why is the switch statement result always null when i return a null value in the default case. And second, What then is the proper way to return a `null` value when none of the patterns match?**

Thank you

EDIT: I am using Intellij IDEA as IDE. Perhaps its an inellij IDEA bug?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS To my knowledge you don't have to use `break statements` in a `pattern matching switch`. I also read a tutorial about [pattern matching switches](https://www.baeldung.com/java-switch-pattern-matching) from baeldung and he isn't using any `break` statements in his `switch` examples either.

Comment: Ah, yes. Forget what i said. I misread the code.

Comment: What is `object`?

Comment: `object` is of type `Object` @Seelenvirtuose

Comment: Please create an issue at the YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA providing the code sample. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your switch statement looks correct. Based solely on the IntelliJ warning, it seems like all your individual cases statements return a null value. As you mention when you change the default to an empty string the warning disappears as now all the case statements do not return null values.

Additionally, when dealing with nulls you could always use Optional values.

Comment: `it seems like all your individual cases statements return a null value`. There is no way Intellij IDEA could know something like that in advance.  It could only detect this if the getters all return null by default, which they don't.